# Move Unity code-as-config to XML when having abstract class in between

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration, unity-container

I've got a working Unity container configured from code. I have to move to xml configuration, but can't make it correctly. I don't know what I am missing - maybe somebody is out there who knows the solution and can help me out!

My solution is about layering my FIX protocol library correctly, to handle different vendor specific messages differently, but to have a good robust backing API for that.
I have two interfaces:

```
public interface ICriteria
{
    bool AreMet(Message message);
}

public interface IConsumer
{
    ICriteria Criteria { get; }
    void HandleMessage(Message message);
}
```

There is a default abstract implementation for the consumers:

```
namespace Fix.MessageHandling
{
    public abstract class Consumer : IConsumer
    {
        private readonly ICriteria criteria;
        protected readonly IProcessor Processor;

        public ICriteria Criteria
        {
            get { return this.criteria; }
        }

        protected Consumer(IProcessor processor, ICriteria criteria)
        {
           //...
        }
    }
}
```

Then I've got some abstract implementations for different FIX message types: each Consumer abstraction has its own Criteria abstraction. (referenced in the constructor as well) e.g.

```
namespace Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport
{
    public abstract class Consumer : MessageHandling.Consumer
    {
        protected Consumer(IProcessor processor, Criteria  criteria)
            : base(processor, criteria)
        {
           // ...
        }
    }
    public abstract class Criteria : ICriteria
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I register the ICriteria instances from code:

```
container.RegisterType<ICriteria, Vendor.Criteria.Spot>("SpotCriteria");
container.RegisterType<ICriteria, Vendor.Criteria.Swap>("SwapCriteria");
// etc.
```

After that I register the IConsumer insatnces, which are in this case ExecutionReportConsumer instances, but I am mapping to IConsumer:

```
container.RegisterType<
            IConsumer,
            Vendor.Consumer.Spot>("SpotConsumer",
            new InjectionConstructor(
                container.Resolve<IProcessor>(),
                container.Resolve<ICriteria>("SpotCriteria")));
// etc.
```

When I resolve IConsumer-s, I can get all my registered Consumers from the UnityContainer:

```
container.ResolveAll<IConsumer>();
```

This is how I tried to do this with xml after defining all the aliases:

```
<register type="ICriteria" mapTo="ForwardCriteria" name="ForwardCriteria" />
<register type="IConsumer" mapTo="ForwardConsumer" name="ForwardConsumer">
  <constructor>
    <param name="processor" dependencyType="IProcessor" />
    <param name="criteria" dependencyType="ExecutionReportCriteria" dependencyName="ForwardCriteria" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```

If I use the xml configuration and I call ResolveAll for IConsumers, I've got an exception

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Fix.MessageHandling.IConsumer", name = "ForwardConsumer".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Criteria does not have an accessible constructor.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Fix.Vendor.Consumer.Forward,ForwardConsumer (mapped from Fix.MessageHandling.IConsumer, ForwardConsumer)
  Resolving parameter "criteria" of constructor Fix.Vendor.Consumer.Forward(Fix.MessageHandling.IProcessor processor, Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport.Criteria criteria)
    Resolving Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport.Criteria,ForwardCriteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, actually I figured this out by myself and I'm a newbie and don't know what to do - so I answer my own question :]

If I register the criteria interface and my concrete criteria implementations to the correct abstract base class, then it works like a charm!

```
<register type="ICriteria" />
<register type="ExecutionReportCriteria" mapTo="ForwardCriteria" name="ForwardCriteria" />
<register type="IConsumer" mapTo="ForwardConsumer" name="ForwardConsumer">
  <constructor>
    <param name="processor" dependencyType="IProcessor" />
    <param name="criteria" dependencyName="ForwardCriteria" />
  </constructor>
</register>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how I managed to get it going:

```xml
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <typeAliases>
    <typeAlias alias="ICriteria"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.ICriteria, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />
    <typeAlias alias="ExecutionReportCriteria"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport.Criteria, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />
    <typeAlias alias="ForwardCriteria"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport.ForwardCriteria, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />

    <typeAlias alias="IConsumer"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.IConsumer, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />
    <typeAlias alias="ForwardConsumer"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.ExecutionReport.ForwardConsumer, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />

    <typeAlias alias="IProcessor"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.IProcessor, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />
    <typeAlias alias="Processor"
               type="Fix.MessageHandling.Processor, MoveUnityCode-as-configToXML" />
  </typeAliases>

  <container>
    <register type="ExecutionReportCriteria" mapTo="ForwardCriteria" name="ForwardCriteria" />
    <register type="IProcessor" mapTo="Processor" />
    <register type="IConsumer" mapTo="ForwardConsumer" name="ForwardConsumer">
      <constructor>
        <param name="processor" dependencyType="IProcessor" />
        <param name="criteria" dependencyType="ExecutionReportCriteria" dependencyName="ForwardCriteria" />
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```